# Char pointer modified by function wont display updated string value correctly

Tags: c, pointers

I have a char pointer in main named sq, and I cast a pointer to sq to the function inttocharp which converts a given integer to a string with all its decimal digits in reversed order. This string is stored in the temporary char array first. I then try to modify the value of sq by assigning the value of the value pointed to by the casted pointer to be equal to first. When I use the command printf("%s \n", *outz); in the function to print the updated string value of the pointer pointed to, it works with no problem, but if I try the same command with sq after the function has finished running, I only get nonsensical symbols. If I replace *outz = first with *outz = "aw", the printf command for sq prints out the expected value "aw". What is the problem and how can I solve it?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

void inttocharp(int numin, char** outz);

int main(void) {
   char* sq;
   inttocharp(13719, &sq);
   printf("%s \n", sq);
   return(0);
}

void inttocharp(int numin, char** outz) {
     char first[33] = "";

     char temp;
     int currnum;
     int divisval = 10;
     do {
        printf("%d \n", numin);
        printf("%d \n", divisval);
        currnum = numin%divisval;
        printf("%d \n", currnum);
        numin -= currnum;
        currnum *= 10;
        currnum /= divisval;
        printf("%d \n\n", currnum);
        temp = 0x30 + currnum;
        strncat(first,&temp,1);
        divisval *= 10;
     } while(numin != 0);
     *outz = first;
     printf("%s \n", *outz);
}
```

Comment: `*outz = first`. Common beginner error. `first` is a local variable. It goes out of scope when the function exits. Any accesses to such a variable results in Undefined Behaviour.

Comment: I don't see why that has to be a problem. I assign *outz to be equal to first, but as far as I know it shouldn't matter whether that variable goes out of scope or not since I have already assigned the value.

Comment: `*outz = first;` is a *pointer* assignment. It only saves the address of the `first` buffer. It doesn't copy the entire string.

Comment: Ok. I get it then.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't exactly know what you hope to achieve here,
Any way the  reason why you are getting junk values is that the character array `char first[30]=""` is local to its function `inttocarp(int numin, char** outz)` and thus has existence only during the execution of the said function.
**Hence `printf("%s \n", *outz)` works fine inside the function**
But as soon as the function ends, scope of `first[30]` ends and it has no existence and thus `outs` is pointing to some memory location containing junk values and **hence you are getting junk values for `sq` in main()**
But when you point a **constant** to `*outz` its scope is end of the program so even in `main()` ,you will get  existence to that memory location containing that **constant**
**Making the deceleration of `first[30]` global will solve your problem..**

Comment: Kaylum explained the problem in his comments to my initial post above. What I didn't realize was that first is just a pointer to the array, not the actual value of the string itself.